# AMPscript error: Data Extension key field has a MAX or unlimited length

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm experiencing a strange error from a LookupRows function. I've thought I've seen every single AMPscript error, until today. The following AMPscript code:

```ampscript
set @sendLogRows = LookupRows('SendLog', 'SubID', 39739981, 'TriggeredSendID', '66d03afd-07ef-eb11-b856-b883035be801')
```

Returns the error:

> The Data Extension Key field for a LookupRows function call is invalid. The key field has a MAX or unlimited length. Fields with MAX or unlimited length cannot be used as keys.

I get the same error using this DE if I use a Lookup function (with modified arguments).

Here's my DE schema:

[image: DE Schema]

Nothing unusual here, right?

I'm not sure what the 'the Data Extension Key field' actually is. For sake of complete visibility (in case the UI isn't displaying something correctly), I've retrieved the DE field properties using WSProxy. This returns the payload below. Again, all seems as I'd expect. If anyone has an idea of what to try next, I'd be really grateful!

```json
{
   "Status":"OK",
   "RequestID":"355ef440-7912-49c8-8a96-d11631bc4c6c",
   "Results":[
      {
         "Name":"SubID",
         "FieldType":"Number",
         "IsPrimaryKey":false,
         "MaxLength":0,
         "Ordinal":4,
         "DefaultValue":""
      },
      {
         "Name":"TriggeredSendID",
         "FieldType":"Text",
         "IsPrimaryKey":false,
         "MaxLength":0,
         "Ordinal":5,
         "DefaultValue":""
      },
      {
         "Name":"view_email_url",
         "FieldType":"Text",
         "IsPrimaryKey":false,
         "MaxLength":900,
         "Ordinal":9,
         "DefaultValue":""
      },
      {
         "Name":"CampaignName",
         "FieldType":"Text",
         "IsPrimaryKey":false,
         "MaxLength":254,
         "Ordinal":8,
         "DefaultValue":""
      },
      {
         "Name":"ListID",
         "FieldType":"Number",
         "IsPrimaryKey":false,
         "MaxLength":0,
         "Ordinal":2,
         "DefaultValue":""
      },
      {
         "Name":"BatchID",
         "FieldType":"Number",
         "IsPrimaryKey":false,
         "MaxLength":0,
         "Ordinal":3,
         "DefaultValue":""
      },
      {
         "Name":"CampaignID",
         "FieldType":"Text",
         "IsPrimaryKey":false,
         "MaxLength":50,
         "Ordinal":7,
         "DefaultValue":""
      },
      {
         "Name":"ErrorCode",
         "FieldType":"Number",
         "IsPrimaryKey":false,
         "MaxLength":0,
         "Ordinal":6,
         "DefaultValue":""
      },
      {
         "Name":"JobID",
         "FieldType":"Number",
         "IsPrimaryKey":false,
         "MaxLength":0,
         "Ordinal":1,
         "DefaultValue":""
      }
   ],
   "HasMoreRows":false
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is within the `TriggeredSendID` field that has `Text` datatype and no set value for the length, which means it has [unlimited length](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154402/data-extension-maximum-characters-of-text-field/154403). Take into consideration this is an unofficial and not recommended configuration of the field as SF Support told us some time ago.

Moreover, you can do a Lookup to the `TriggeredSendID` field to retrieve the value from it but you cannot use this field as a filter (as what you are doing in the LookupRows), since it might contain unsupported value's length and thus throws the error.

Comment: Oh, how did I miss that??? The bizarre thing is that this is a SendLog DE (based on the SendLog template) and that field is a default field in the template!

Comment: I guess it is a very old SendLog DE that has a `TriggeredSendID` field without length ([Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-data-management/collect-data-with-a-send-log) depicts that as well) because if you would create a new one now, it would have length = 36 characters in the field `TriggeredSendID`. Probably, that was a reason to add the length to the field to improve efficiency and prevent such errors.

Comment: To add more clarity to this, when you use a field in lookups the system tries to build an index on that field to return results quicker, and an index can't be built on this field length

Comment: @Niko I've just created a new SendLog on that account and it still has an unlimited field length, which can't be changed. Very odd. I even tried updating using the API and that didn't work. I'll just create a duplicate send log and update it from a query. What a bore.