# Retrieve QR CODE from Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

my use case is as follows:
a qr code is generated from an external system. To avoid making an api call each time to use it in the email template, I would like to understand if there is an api call to retrieve me the qr code image and save it in a string on a given extension.

does anyone know if this is possible?

thank you,

Mary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the Content Builder API to upload the image directly to Content Builder:

> Marketing developers, service providers, and third-party developers
> can create and manipulate marketing content using the Content Builder
> REST API.

Here's an example API call to create an image:

```
POST /asset/v1/content/assets

{
    "name": "MakanaLogoHeaderNavy2",
    "assetType": {
        "name": "png",
        "id": 28
    },
    "FileProperties": {
        "fileName": "MakanaLogoHeaderNavy2.png"
    },
    "file": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfQAAABrCAYAAACBkXCoAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAGT9JREFUeNrsnVtMXEl6xz9owOALY214bOzLZbiPJYM/TebJn6XzhdYfXUPYiFsvGlGCjEYV2sGzPZWzpltbCSBab0nQdfZFe+bM3TE+O5CYII="
}
```

Or, you could save either the Base64-encoded string of the image or a public url linking to the image in a Data Extension using the Asynchronous DE API:

Here's an example with a base64:

```
POST /data/v1/async/dataextensions/{id}/rows

{
   "items": [{
      "QRcodeName":"qr-code-1",
      "base64" : "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfQAAABrCAYAAACBkXCoAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAGT9JREFUeNrsnVtMXEl6xz9owOALY214bOzLZbiPJYM/TebJn6XzhdYfXUPYiFsvGlGCjEYV2sGzPZWzpltbCSBab0nQdfZFe+bM3TE+O5CYII="
   }]
}
```

And an example with a url:

```
POST /data/v1/async/dataextensions/{id}/rows

{
   "items": [{
      "QRcodeName":"qr-code-1",
      "url" : "https://public-url.com/qr-code-1.jpg"
   }]
}
```

References:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/createAsset.html
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/insertDataExtensionIDAsync.html

Comment: hi zuzannamj thank you so much for your responde. if i were to use example with a url how do i then pass it to base64 and then use it as an image into template email?

Comment: You can use the base64 string in an `img` tag in HTML: `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4/8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="/>`

Comment: If I use the url" : "https://public-url.com/qr-code-1.jpg"" how can I use base64?

Comment: They are two different things, you either use one or another, not both at the same time. Either use  the base64 string: `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4/8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="/>` or use the public url: `<img src="http://public-url.com/qr-code-1.jpg"/>`

Comment: ok thank you very much zuzannamj, while if i wanted to use the Base64-encoded string of the image to the image in a Data Extension using the Asynchronous DE API: i have to save the base64 field but it returns me a value of about 20k, and it would not fit into the marketing cloud field limits. how would i proceed?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154402/data-extension-maximum-characters-of-text-field