# Concatenate ordered CampaignMembers in SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, automationstudio

I have a data extension where I store all my CampaignMembers from Salescloud:

| CampaignId | ContactId | CampaignMemberId | Name | CampaignMemberCreatedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 701090000018Dmf | 0030900000fydTaAAI | 00v0900000IFESBAA5 | Summercampaign_2022 | 5/30/2022 |
| 642245244050dmS | 0030900000fydTaAAI | 00v0900000IFEBEEA1 | Wintercampaign_2022 | 10/24/2022 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

And another master data extension where I store all data about an individual Contact:

| ContactId | Firstname | Lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0030900000fydTaAAI | John | Doe |
| ... | ... | ... |

Now I want to write all CampaignMembers comma-sepparated in a new field on the Contact data extension. Since a field in sfmc is limited to 4000 characters, I want to order the CampaignMember on the CampaignMemberCreatedDate displaying only the Names of the newest ones until 4000 chars are reached:

| ContactId | Firstname | Lastname | Campaigns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0030900000fydTaAAI | John | Doe | Wintercampaign_2022,Summercampaign_2022 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

To achieve that I use the following SQL script which is working, but won't order my CampaignMembers correctly based on **CampaignMemberCreatedDate**:

```
SELECT c.ContactId as ContactId, LEFT(c.Name, 4000) AS Campaigns
FROM (
    SELECT ContactId, Name =
        STUFF ((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Name
        FROM (
            SELECT TOP 2000 
            ContactId, Name, CampaignMemberCreatedDate
            FROM Campaigns
            ORDER BY CampaignMemberCreatedDate DESC
            ) b
        WHERE b.ContactId = a.ContactId
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
    FROM Campaigns a
    GROUP BY ContactId
) c
```

Could you help me out on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated query as per your requirement to SORT based on **CampaignMemberCreatedDate**
You change the ORDER by **ASC** or **DESC**

```SQL
SELECT OutTab.contactid,
       campaignname = Stuff ((SELECT ',' + InrTab.campaignname
                              FROM   test_de InrTab
                              WHERE  InrTab.contactid = OutTab.contactid
                              ORDER  BY InrTab.campaignmembercreateddate ASC
                              FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
                      , 1, 1,
                      Space(0))
FROM   test_de OutTab
GROUP  BY OutTab.contactid
```

> Output in **Ascending**

| Contactid | CampaignName |
| --- | --- |
| 0030900000fydTaAAI | Summercampaign_2022,Wintercampaign_2022 |

```SQL
 SELECT OutTab.contactid,
       campaignname = Stuff ((SELECT ',' + InrTab.campaignname
                              FROM   test_de InrTab
                              WHERE  InrTab.contactid = OutTab.contactid
                              ORDER  BY InrTab.campaignmembercreateddate DESC
                              FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
                      , 1, 1,
                      Space(0))
FROM   test_de OutTab
GROUP  BY OutTab.contactid
```

> Output in **DESCENDING**

| Contactid | CampaignName |
| --- | --- |
| 0030900000fydTaAAI | Wintercampaign_2022,Summercampaign_2022 |

Note: You can OMIT the code to handle 4000 char limit, by leaving the lenght field blank as suggested here [data extension: maximum characters of text field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154402/data-extension-maximum-characters-of-text-field)

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I wish to order my dataset on the CampaignMemberCreatedDate which is a datetime field. Sorry if that was unclear in my question.

Comment: @fgadie I have updated my SQL as per your requirement, hope this was your requirement!