# Building an email from JSON Payload that is over 4000 characters (SFMC)

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, json, transactional-messaging-api

I have been testing using GTL in SFMC to build an email from a JSON payload stored in an email. The reason for this is that there is often multiple products the customer can purchase, and they want to stop storing/sending over the whole HTML table.

The testing has gone well so far however I've been notified that the payloads can swell in size to over 4000 characters which is the field limit in SFMC.

I have tried the solution mentioned below to circumvent this however after creating the extension, the UI limits me to 255 characters.

[data extension: maximum characters of text field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154402/data-extension-maximum-characters-of-text-field)

Is there any other potential solutions to receive nested JSON in marketing cloud for parsing, that is over 4000 characters?

Thanks

Found Solution:
The original data extension I created was created using email studio. However I made the mistake of trying to insert JSON via the UI, which is limited! However importing via API/file import works just fine. Appreciate the support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust the field length in Email Studio, as it is not possible in Contact Builder. When you start editing fields in a data extension, find the field you want to extend beyond 4000 characters:
[image]

Remove the value in the *Length* field:
[image]

Once you save the fields, the field shows an empty value for *Length*:
[image]

Checking the field in Contact Builder confirms this:

[image]

Now you can accommodate your complete payload into this field.

Answer (score 0):

Create the Data Extension in Email Studio and leave the character length field blank when you save it. Make sure you do this in Email Studio, not Contact Builder.

Answer (score 0):

The original data extension I created was created using email studio. However I made the mistake of trying to insert JSON via the UI, which is limited! However importing via API/file import works just fine. Appreciate the support